# Angular 17 giving me a "main.ts" missing error and I can't fix it

Tags: angular

Yesterday, I created a brand new Angular 17 project from scratch using "ng new (foldername)". I added some content, everything was working fine. I left my computer on, and went to bed.

This morning, I woke up and went to go continue my work, however, when I do an "ng s" to start the program, it is now giving me an error:

```
- Building...X [ERROR] File 'src\main.ts' is missing from the TypeScript compilation. [plugin angular-compiler]

  Ensure the file is part of the TypeScript program via the 'files' or 'include' property.
```

This being a brand new project, I haven't touched this file, and I haven't imported any other files. All I changed was some HTML and CSS, no project files. Anyway, so this file exists and is in the correct path, and looks correct in the files.

Since I just started the project, I decided maybe it was just "a fluke" and decided to create another brand new project, and then I could just copy my changes into that, and be back up and running, right? Wrong.

So I created a new project, same thing, "ng new (folder)". Then when I go to run it... SAME ERROR. On a brand new project.

Ok, so maybe Angular is corrupt somehow?

So I uninstalled Angular using npm, AND I made sure to clear the cache as well, just in case. I checked, Anguar was gone. Great. Reinstalled Angular 17 clean. Should be good to go now, right?

Created a new project. Same error.

I'm at a loss now. Why is this happening? Why can't I create new project without getting this error? How can I fix it? I'm dead in the water at the moment.

Comment: Have you installed the CLI globally, with npm -g, or local to the project? Because i've just created a new project, and it works. The only difference could be this, if you installed it globally. 
My package.json is equal to your's (saw it on gh issue)
Node: 18.18.2 
Npm: 9.8.1
Angular-cli: ^17.0.1

Comment: I installed it globally. npm

Comment: FWIW, one thing I just tried is to update to the latest version of Node.js, just to see if it would make a difference. So currently, npm v.10.2.3 and node v20.9.0 and Angular 17.02

Comment: Angular CLI: 17.0.0
Node: 20.9.0
Package Manager: npm 10.2.3
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 17.0.2

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1700.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.0.0
@angular-devkit/core            17.0.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.0.0
@angular/cli                    17.0.0
@angular/ssr                    17.0.0
@schematics/angular             17.0.0
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.2.2
zone.js                         0.14.2

Comment: Have you solved? Your CLI version is 17.0.0, not 17.0.1 which I have. So the answer below may be right

Answer (score 1):

this is a [known issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26284). And a fix was released yesterday.

Can you trying updating the cli & builder packages to `17.0.1`.

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.1",
"@angular/cli": "^17.0.1",
```

Comment: Thank you, at least it's not just me or my system. I looked in package.json, and the files listed above are already at 17.0.1, as shown. Any other thoughts on what to try? I'm surprised that the issue you linked to was marked as "resolved" by the team, since it is clearly not working still. :(

Comment: This issue is not fixed in angular version 17.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution, and did open a ticket with the Angular team about it. I honestly can't tell you why it ever worked, or why it works for most people and not others, however, I can tell you what fixed it. Another user on the Angular support forums tried this fix as well and confirmed it worked for them as well.

Go into the angular.json file, and add a "preserveSymlinks": true as indicated below:

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
      "options": {
        "preserveSymlinks": true,
```

Comment: Do you know what version this issue will be fixed? I still see this issue in 17.0.3.